# Ionic 2 - Auth Password reset error

Tags: authentication, service, ionic2

I'm trying to implement the Ionic Cloud Auth Service and now I want to do the password reset like it is described [here](http://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/#password-reset). So I have a text field where the user can enter his email and a button. If the button is tapped I call this function:

```
email: any;

sendPasswordRequest() {
        this.auth.requestPasswordReset(this.email);
        this.navCtrl.push(ConfirmPasswordResetPage);
}
```

And the form looks like this:

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" stacked>E-Mail</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button (click)="sendPasswordRequest();">New Password</button>
```

But I get the following error when I press the button:

> error_handler.js:46 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Someone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

have found this to work but remember that 'sendPasswordResetEmail' is a promise...so

```
this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email).then(() =>{
    this.navCtrl.push(ConfirmPasswordResetPage);
  }).catch( e =>{
  console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
  });
```

I'm using the AngularFire2 package here.